# WCF MSMQ Message queue not being processed

Tags: wcf, iis, msmq, was

I have setup a WCF service that i am running on IIS 7 that uses MSMQ message queueing, The messages are being put into the queue correctly on the server but the WCF service isn't processing them so the queue just builds up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @FelicePollano suggests, this may be a permissions problem. Here are specific items to check:

1. Make sure that account for the Net.Msmq Listener Adapter Windows service has these permissions to the queue that your service is using: receive message, peek message, send message, get properties, and get permissions. You have to go to Message Queuing node in Computer Manager control panel app to set/check these. By default, this is the Network Service account.
2. Make sure the account for service site AppPool also has permissions to the queue. The permission should be set to full control.

If these are not set up this way then make the changes, restart the AppPool and also restart the Net.Msmq Listener Adapter Windows service. If everything is working correctly the queue should automatically drain itself.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the queue is visible from the service. Sometimes if you create a queue with the logged user the IIS worker process cannot acces it.